# Merging Class Instance Values into Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```py
from ast import alias
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from uuid import UUID
app = FastAPI()
# ROSTER = {
#     'Hero-1' : {'alias':'spider-man','name':'peter parker'},
#     'Hero-2' : {'alias':'spider-woman','name':'jessica drew'},
#     'Hero-3' : {'alias':'kid-spider','name':'miles morales'}
# }
ROSTER = {}
class SuperHero(BaseModel):
    id: UUID
    alias: str
    name: str
    rating: int
@app.get('/')
async def get_all_heroes():
    return ROSTER
def populate_roster():
    SH1 = SuperHero(id='b14f73c6-0b48-11ed-861d-0242ac120002',alias='Spider-Man',name='Peter Parker',rating='10')
    SH2 = SuperHero(id='b14f7592-0b48-11ed-861d-0242ac120002',alias='Spider-Woman',name='Jessica Drew',rating='10')
    SH3 = SuperHero(id='b14f78bc-0b48-11ed-861d-0242ac120002',alias='Agent Venom',name='Eddie Brock',rating='9')
    SH4 = SuperHero(id='b14f79b6-0b48-11ed-861d-0242ac120002',alias='Dr. Strange',name='Stephan Strange',rating='9')
    # for i in range (1,6):
    ROSTER.update(SH1)
    ROSTER.update(SH2)
    ROSTER.update(SH3)
    ROSTER.update(SH4)
populate_roster()
print(ROSTER)
```

The issue with my code is it's only printing the value of `SH4` at the moment, I understand it's because it's "over-writing" the same index. I am trying to find a way in which I can append `SH1,SH2,SH3,SH4` into my dictionary.

I have tried `ChainMap()` storing values in separate `dict` to merge them with `**` but I can't seem to get the desired output.

I do know I can move it to `list` and then use `append` but moving main `list` to `dict` back again is little tricky..

EDIT : Added Comment

Comment: edit post instead of writing a comment

Comment: What output are you expecting? Something more like the `ROSTER` shown in the commented out code? If so, `dict.update` is the wrong tool, you want to be creating new inner dictionaries, and only after that adding them as values (to new keys) in the outer dict.